# ¿Hay un origen conocido para la expresión "para muestra un botón"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos

La expresión "para muestra un botón" es una expresión que siempre he tenido problemas en entender, porque me parecía que mis interlocutores siempre la usaban de una manera no muy coherente los unos con los otros.

La expresión significa, de acuerdo al [Centro Virtual Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59279&Lng=0)

> que no resulta necesario mostrarlo o enseñarlo todo, ya que de un ejemplo se puede deducir fácilmente todo lo que falta por descubrir.

¿Hay un origen conocido para la expresión "para muestra un botón"? ¿Es una de esas expresiones como "no dejar títere con cabeza" o "llevar al huerto" que viene de la literatura?¿O es por el contrario una expresión popular?

Comment: El DLE registra [_botón de muestra_](http://dle.rae.es/botón) como "ejemplo o indicio de algo", que supongo que vendrá de las muestras de botones de los sastres, que viendo uno ya sabes cómo son los demás.

Answer (score 1):

Me sorprende ver que el CVC no haya sido capaz de ayudar. Desgraciadamente poco parece que se sabe del origen de este refrán. Para hacerlo peor, aunque el CVC dé solo una definición, parece que en realidad tiene dos significados - el del CVC, y el que @Charlie comentó en tu pregunta:

> 1. Que no resulta necesario mostrarlo o enseñarlo todo, ya que de un ejemplo se puede deducir fácilmente todo lo que falta por descubrir.
> 2. Que con ver a uno has visto a todos.

De la misma manera que he visto más de una definición, el origen que conocía por medio de voz y el único origen que fui capaz de encontrar en Google son distintos. Para hacerlo más complicado, hay dos orígenes muy similares que justifican ambas definiciones de manera distinta:

> 1. Se dice que Paul von Hindenburg, un mariscal de Prusia, creía que se podía juzgar a alguien por los botones de su chaqueta, diciendo que "aquellos que se olvidan de lo pequeño, se olvidarán de lo grande también", y por tanto "para muestra basta un botón". (Definición 1)
> 2. Hay quien dice que viene de los sastres, que debido al tiempo que pasan trabajando en cada prenda, y a sus ojos atentos al detalle, saben identificar una prenda en la que han trabajado solo viendo un botón de aquella. (Definición 1)
> 3. Que los sastres trabajan de manera tan precisa que uno no podría encontrar diferencia entre los botones de una prenda hecha por un sastre, y por tanto "si has visto uno, has visto todos".

La primera es la que encontré en Google y las otras las que he oído. Personalmente me parece a mí que lo más "correcto" es usar la definición que el CVC da, y el origen más probable sea el segundo, especialmente teniendo en cuenta las historias populares de sastres siendo usados por detectives para ayudar encontrar al criminal después de haber recogido un botón de su chaqueta en la escena del crimen (ahora mismo el único ejemplo que me viene a la cabeza es de un *anime*, pero me suena haberlo oído en más historias que esa).

Answer (score 1):

La primera opción es imposible, porque ya Benito Pérez Galdós lo usa hacia 1886 en Fortuata y Jacinta. Jacinta sospecha de la infidelidad de su esposo Juan porque ha visto, entre sus ropas, un botón de mujer. Juan le responde: "¡Cuántas veces pensamos mal de un sujeto, fundándonos en hablillas del vulgo o en cualquier dato inseguro, como por ejemplo, un pelo, un botón!... Y después de mirar bien el hecho, ¿qué resulta? Que no basta para muestra un botón, que el que se cuelga de un cabello se cae". O el refrán sale directamente de esta obra (porque encaja a la perfección en el contexto), o bien Pérez Galdós está citando un refrán ya conocido. Lo mismo vale para la expresión "colgarse de un pelo". Habría que ver si las expresiones están testimoniadas antes de 1886.